# What is the correct word usage of "spends a lot" in this context?

Tags: single-word-requests, business-language

I am in the process of writing a business plan and want to write that the organization's target audience spends a lot. However, I have to mention this a lot and I can not figure out how to write this phrase in one or two words for example like: “Athletic Target Audience”.

Comment: How is this about anything but vocabulary or choice of style, please?

I'm sorry to suggest that it doesn't work because either it's obvious how and why these people spend more, or your real target audience is simply "people with money" and no other demographic measure applies.

Comment: Unquestionably in this context, which you will all recall does matter, you do not want to denigrate the customer in any way, whether in public or private, e.g., internal communications. It would, furthermore, jeopardize your own positions should you be fortunate enough to still have them.

Answer (score 0):

How about **large market**?

Example 1:

> There is a **large market** around the world for athletic equipment.

[Example 2](https://www.statista.com/statistics/1000592/sports-equipment-market-size-worldwide/):

> The statistic shows the value of the **global sports equipment market** from 2018 to 2025. In 2018, the global sports equipment market was valued at approximately 70.1 billion U.S. dollars and was forecast to reach a value of 89 billion U.S. dollars by 2025.

You also might want to consider the definition of **market size**. From [Business Dictionary](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/market-size.html), for example:

> [**market size**](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/market-size.html): The number of individuals in a certain market who are potential buyers and/or sellers of a product or service. Companies are interested in knowing the market size before launching a new product or service in an area.

Whether a market is large of small is relative to the sizes of other markets.

Answer (score -1):

You can consider using 'High-end customers'